# Access 2007 Nest parameterful query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

My problem is straight forward:

I have Query A:

```
SELECT Old, New
FROM MAPPING
WHERE Old = [Param];
```

I now need a Query B that calls Query A by giving it a value for [Param].

Is that possible without VBA ?

Thanks in advance
Miloud

Comment: Can you show us what Query B looks like?

Comment: Can you give more detail on what the queries are trying to do? I don't think it is possible to pass an argument like you are trying to accomplish, but there might be an alternate way to construct the queries to avoid needing to.

Comment: Well Query B will need to do like:

    SELECT QueryA(Param)
    FROM  SomeTable
    WHERE
          SomeTable.Param < 10

Comment: This seems more like a function. And a function that returns 2 values at that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. But you can replace your parameter in QueryA by a reference to an unbound control. This way you can set the value of the control and queryB can silently call queryA. In the same way, you could also replace your parameter by a UDF.

Answer (score 1):

It soundn like you want to create a nested select query.  If you are doing a select query in B, just put it inside parentheses where `[Param];` is.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you want to pull the results from Query A, based on data from a Query B, is that correct?

A nested query is probably your best bet.  What B looks like will depend on what you want to do, but try a model similar to this:

> SELECT Old, New FROM MAPPING WHERE Old
>   = (SELECT somefield FROM sometable WHERE somefield = somevalue);

Comment: This is equivalent to a JOIN, no?